# MySQL aggregate function in INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql

This is the query I am working with:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mav_proposals`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id AS mav_id, 
             mav_proposal_id
   FROM mav) AS mav ON `mav_proposals`.`mav_id` = `mav`.`mav_id`
WHERE `paid_at` IS NULL
  AND (`mav`.`mav_proposal_id` IS NULL
       OR `mav_proposals`.`sold_at` IS NOT NULL)
  AND `hidden` = 0
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `mav`
     WHERE `mav_proposals`.`mav_id` = `mav`.`id`)
```

---

Here's a rextester for the question: http://rextester.com/HDI75486

I would like that only the most recent `mav_proposal` is shown for each `mav`.

This is the desired result:

```
+-----+--------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|  id | mav_id | buyer_id | price |          created_at | sold_at | paid_at | hidden | mav_id | mav_proposal_id |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|  1  |      1 |     3704 | 10800 | 15.03.2017 17:56:25 |    NULL |    NULL |  false |      1 |            NULL |
|  4  |      2 |     4462 | 10800 | 09.03.2017 16:27:22 |    NULL |    NULL |  false |      2 |            NULL |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

I tried by using the aggregate `MAX(mav.id)` function inside the first INNER JOIN, however without success.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show sample _table_ data along with the expected output in _tabular_ form?  It's a bit hard to go with JSON data and no table structure.

Comment: Can you show exactly what aggregate function did you tried?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please tell us precisely how you will decide what is "most recent." You don't have any `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data items, so you're leaving us, and perhaps yourself, guessing how recency works in your data system.

Comment: I've edited the question. Now that should be better.

Comment: And whilst we're perusing meta questions, why not read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

1. Seems to me you need a query for all mav_proposals table which gets the max per mav_ID. `(SELECT max(mav_proposal_ID) max_Proposal, Mav_ID
     FROM mav_proposals
     GROUP BY MAV_ID)`
2. I have no idea what the exists is buying you... so I eliminated it
3. I have no idea why an inline `mav` exists.  so I eliminated it.

ASSUMPTIONS:

1. This does assume that the max(ID) of max_proposal will always be the "Newest" for a mav_ID.

Accepting this we can incorporated the inline view as a join an exists or an in: here's the join approach (2nd fastest usually)

```
SELECT m.Id, Buyer_ID, price, Created_at, Sold_at, Paid_at, hidden,  m.ID, mav_proposal_ID
FROM MAV M
INNER JOIN mav_proposals MP 
 on M.id = MP.mav_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(ID) max_Proposal, Mav_ID
            FROM mav_proposals
            GROUP BY MAV_ID) A
  on MP.ID = A.Max_Proposal
 and M.ID = A.Mav_ID
WHERE MP.paid_at IS NULL
  AND (M.mav_proposal_id IS NULL  
    OR MP.sold_at IS NOT NULL)
  AND MP.hidden = 0
```

Here's the in approach (slowest usually):

```
SELECT m.Id, Buyer_ID, price, Created_at, Sold_at, Paid_at, hidden,  m.ID, mav_proposal_ID
FROM MAV M
INNER JOIN mav_proposals MP 
 on M.id = MP.mav_id

WHERE MP.paid_at IS NULL
  AND (M.mav_proposal_id IS NULL  
    OR MP.sold_at IS NOT NULL)
  AND MP.hidden = 0 

 and (MP.ID, M.ID)  IN (SELECT max(ID) max_Proposal, Mav_ID
            FROM mav_proposals
            GROUP BY MAV_ID)
```

and here's the exists (fastest usually)

```
SELECT m.Id, Buyer_ID, price, Created_at, Sold_at, Paid_at, hidden,  m.ID, mav_proposal_ID
FROM MAV M
INNER JOIN mav_proposals MP 
 on M.id = MP.mav_id

WHERE MP.paid_at IS NULL
  AND (M.mav_proposal_id IS NULL  
    OR MP.sold_at IS NOT NULL)
  AND MP.hidden = 0 
 and Exists (SELECT max(ID) max_Proposal, Mav_ID
             FROM mav_proposals MP1
             GROUP BY MAV_ID
             HAVING max_proposal = mp.id
                and mp1.mav_id = m.id)
```

Comment: Updated. with a running query.

Comment: The query does indeed give the expected data set, however it dramatically changes the result structure. Isn't there a way to maintain it?

Comment: Just needed to select the correct columns instead of the select * you originally had. (updated)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM `mav_proposals`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id AS mav_id, 
             mav_proposal_id
   FROM mav group by id) AS mav ON `mav_proposals`.`mav_id` = `mav`.`mav_id`
WHERE `paid_at` IS NULL
  AND (`mav`.`mav_proposal_id` IS NULL
       OR `mav_proposals`.`sold_at` IS NOT NULL)
  AND `hidden` = 0
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `mav`
     WHERE `mav_proposals`.`mav_id` = `mav`.`id`)
```

Basically I just added group by in your inner join. I'm not sure if you want to get rid of the duplicate.

Comment: It does not solve the issue, you can see that the same mav_id is used in multiple proposals. I only want the most recent proposal for each MAV. http://puu.sh/vocDR/6970b1a411.png